# Can git and subversion play nice together?

Tags: windows, svn, git

I have recently decided to take the git plunge, and am really enjoying using git, even on Windows.

My current open source project [lives on subversion](http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/checkout), all devs are familiar with subversion so I would like to keep subversion as the "source of truth" for now.

Nonetheless, I want to use git, so I went ahead and created a copy of the source [on github](https://github.com/SamSaffron/Media-Browser/tree/master) using [git svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). All my work is done against the source in github and I push my changes to github. Once every few days I also push my changes to svn and rebase.

The initial import seemed to go ok, but now every time I do a "git svn rebase" I keep on getting conflicts, even on files I have not changed in my get repository. This is causing me [much pain](http://github.com/sambo99/Media-Browser/commit/c120af912012219f6947727109d7f5863a8a85ce).

Eg.

```
$ git svn rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Added git ignore file
c:/Users/sam/Desktop/MediaBrowserGit/trunk/.git/rebase-apply/patch:12: trailing
whitespace.
*/obj/*
error: .gitignore: already exists in index
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
:12: trailing whitespace.
*/obj/*
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Added git ignore file

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".

rebase refs/remotes/git-svn: command returned error: 1
```

My questions:

1. Is there any way I can tell git to sync itself up with svn using svn as the source, so I can start with a clean slate. (export latest, check in changes and reset the svn refs somewhere)
2. Are there any tips and tricks to getting this scenario to work consistently?
3. Should I have the [core.safecrlf and core.autocrlf](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2009/01/handling-crlf-in-git/) options set to true? It seems I will need a bit of hoop jumping.

Related:

- http://kerneltrap.org/index.php?q=mailarchive/git/2008/4/16/1450834/thread
- http://markmail.org/message/vaois4kkr5ggugqs#query:git%20crlf+page:1+mid:i4flex6vmt5tdala+state:results
- http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=271

It seems getting line endings right is a bit of a black art.

(I realize that this question probably needs to be expanded, please comment on the places that need expanding)

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting line-ending conflicts? Git has a few configuration properties you can set that change how it handles the end of line characters. I have the following set:

```
# this makes git NOT attempt to convert line endings on commit and checkout
core.autocrlf=false

# this makes git check if the conversion done by autocrlf would be reversible
# this is probably not required because I do not have autocrlf turned on
core.safecrlf=true
```

Note that I am on windows, all my coworkers are on windows and I am interfacing with SVN through git-svn. These settings seem to do the trick for me.

[image]
<sub>(source: [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/works-on-my-machine-starburst.png))</sub>

Comment: sometimes ... the line ending ones less annoying, it seems to say something along the lines of "squelching xxx line ending conflict" the ones that get me are the non-line ending conflicts. it says a whole file is in conflict state when I never touched it ...

Comment: Sounds like you are getting line ending conflicts - if the whole file is inconflict this is probably because something changed all the line endings

Comment: Whats the best practice when it comes to line-endings, git, svn and interoperability on windows?

Comment: well I started getting the problems with core.autocrlf = false , but the problem persist with the repo being true, it seems i manage to mess stuff up to a pretty bad state ... I may need to run a script to clean this mess up

Comment: You might now have some files in the repository with line endings that you don't want - so changing autocrlf might now mean that git will think they have changed. You should be able to fix those up by checking them back in, I guess